# MSVC error - error C2373: 'description': redefinition; different type modifiers

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


namespace MyNS {
    struct Test1 {};
    template <typename > class Test;

    template <> class Test<Test1> {
        public:
            constexpr static char const *description[] = { "X1", "Y1",};
    };
    constexpr char const *Test<Test1>::description[];
    static const char * getDesc(int i) {
        return MyNS::Test<MyNS::Test1>::description[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << MyNS::getDesc(0) << std::endl;
}
```

This fails with MSVC (**error C2373: 'description': redefinition; different type modifiers**), but compiles successfully on GCC 4.8.

Is there a workaround to successfully build with MSVC and GCC both?

Comment: Fyi, it also compiles without issue on clang 3.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that MSVC wants us to precise the array length, this should work :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


namespace MyNS {
    struct Test1 {};
    template <typename > class Test;

    template <> class Test<Test1> {
        public:
            constexpr static char const *description[2] = { "X1", "Y1",};
    };
    constexpr char const *Test<Test1>::description[];
    static const char * getDesc(int i) {
        return MyNS::Test<MyNS::Test1>::description[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << MyNS::getDesc(0) << std::endl;
}
```

**EDIT : You just have to precise the length in the first definition.**

Answer (score 2):

Remove the redefinition of description and it compiles. You also need tor return a value from main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


namespace MyNS {
    struct Test1 {};
    template <typename > class Test;

    template <> class Test<Test1> {
        public:
            constexpr static char const *description[] = { "X1", "Y1",};
    };

    //constexpr char const *Test<Test1>::description[];

    static const char * getDesc(int i) {
        return Test<Test1>::description[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << MyNS::getDesc(0) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It will work in this very simple "reproduction code" but if you want to link to your constexpr from another obj you need to redefine it in another cpp for instance.

Comment: Put the whole class definition in a header file. You will need the data assignment to go with a constexpr definition wherever you put it.

Comment: You are right, I thought it was required because I once faced an unreferenced symbol error at link time with static constexpr. But not now! thanks!

Comment: Removing the definition from namespace causes the compilation to fail on GCC. So, M'handBOUGHIAS 's solution works for me.

Comment: You would keep it in the namespace in the header also. The duplicate definition doesn't make sense with a constexp. The compiler needs to always know the values. That was also just a response to the other comment. The code works as is with just the line comment out. No need to give an array size.